# Creating an Efficient Function

Tags: c++, qt, function, qt-creator, repeat

I am a beginner in my fourth week learning C++; I had been working on CodeBlocks, but due to my interest in making GUIs I switched to Qt Creator. Back in CodeBlocks I had created a function that would avoid all the repetition in the code below, only changing the "TXT FILE". However, with Qt Creator's "specialized" C++ I am having trouble making sense of how to create a function to avoid all this repetition.

Any ideas? (I'm too far into this Qt project to go back to CodeBlocks.)

The "TXT FILE" changes depending on which `RadioButton` the user selects.

```
void MovierRec::on_searchButton_clicked()
{
    int randomValue = qrand() % 100;
    QList<QString> titles;
    if(ui->modernButton->isChecked())
           {
               QFile myfile(":/classics.txt");
               if (myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
               {
                   QTextStream in(&myfile);
                   while (!in.atEnd())
                   {
                       QString line = in.readLine();
                       titles.append(line);
                   }
                   myfile.close();
                   ui->textBrowser->setPlainText (titles[randomValue]);
                }
           }
    else if(ui->romanceButton->isChecked())
           {
               QFile myfile(":/romance.txt");
               if (myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
               {
                   QTextStream in(&myfile);
                   while (!in.atEnd())
                   {
                       QString line = in.readLine();
                       titles.append(line);
                   }
                   myfile.close();
                   ui->textBrowser->setPlainText (titles[randomValue]);
                }
           }

    else if(ui->scifiButton->isChecked())
           {
               QFile myfile(":/scifi.txt");
               if (myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
               {
                   QTextStream in(&myfile);
                   while (!in.atEnd())
                   {
                       QString line = in.readLine();
                       //titles.append(line);
                   }
                   myfile.close();
                   ui->textBrowser->setPlainText (titles[randomValue]);
                }
           }
```

Comment: QtCreator doesn't do "specialized C++", just plain C++. Qt uses some macros to have additional code generated, that doesn't make it another language or any normal C++ code not working.

Comment: Probably something about your terminology, but what does IDE choice have to do with creating functions? Also, Qt Creator is just normal IDE with integrated editor, what do you mean "specialized C++"? Are you mixing Qt (the GUI framework) and Qt Creator (the IDE, suitable for all C and C++ coding, not just Qt), and the "Designer" component of Qt Creator?

Comment: Also, nitpick for everybody saying *QT*, which means (at least) Apple QuickTime. *Qt* is the C++ GUI framework.

Comment: I guess what happened is that I got a little overwhelmed by the way in which I had to use this "Q" before everything (as in QList, QVector, QFile, etc) in contrast to the way I was working in CodeBlocks ( simply using TextStream, Vector, etc). 

Probably not explaining myself right due to a lack of experience, but the point is I was having trouble "wording" the function, not with the logic of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generic programming issue, could refactor code in a better way:

```
// I didn't dig into every line of the code. just provide the refactor idea here
void getTitle(const QString& file_name, QList<QString>& titles;)
{
   QFile myfile(file_name);
   if (myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
   {
     QTextStream in(&myfile);
     while (!in.atEnd())
     {
       QString line = in.readLine();
       titles.append(line);
     }
   myfile.close();
 }
}

void MovierRec::on_searchButton_clicked()
{
    int randomValue = qrand() % 100;
    QList<QString> titles;
    if(ui->modernButton->isChecked())
    {
        getTitle("classics.txt", titles);       
    }
    else if(ui->romanceButton->isChecked())
    {
        getTitle("romance.txt", titles);       
    }
    else if(ui->scifiButton->isChecked())
    {
        getTitle("scifi.txt", titles);
   }
   ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(titles[randomValue]); // move the dup action to the end
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I will work on it and see if i can implement it properly! THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: YOUR CODE WORKS AS SMOOTH AS BUTTER and Thanks for the quick lesson! Definitely will look up to this on future coding.

Answer (score 0):

QT is well known for Signals and Slots. Each button can be connected to a slot. For Example in your case. You can connect each radio button to a slot. in order to do that, Open ur GUI form, right click on the radio button and select "Go To Slot", and select the slot you want to connect to.
This will create an empty function in ur .cpp file.

Now write your code for that button. And this function is called only when that particular Button is pressed/clicked .

example:

```
     void ClassA::on_radioButton_clicked()
     {
         // write your code inside this function for , when this button is checked
      }
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue. If you have other query , please provide more information.